# setting a cronjob in IST time

Tags: ubuntu, cron, timezone

I am trying to set a cronjob run in a different timezone. I've googled a lot and found editing `/etc/default/cron` is the way to go.  But this file is deprecated and I see the following message, so I added `TZ=IST` in the file `/etc/init/cron.conf`. I'm not sure this will work, any tips on how to move forward please?

```
# This file has been deprecated. Please add custom options for cron to
# /etc/init/cron.conf and/or /etc/init/cron.override directly. See
# the init(5) man page for more information
```

I'm using cron 3.0pl1-120ubuntu4 on Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 3):

#### one cron in a different TZ

You could try setting the variable `CRON_TZ` instead of `TZ`. These options seem to be distro specific. I looked in the following man pages (`man 5 crontab` then search for `TZ`) for both Fedora and Ubuntu.

Fedora has it as `CRON_TZ=IST` while Ubuntu states it like this:

> The cron daemon runs with a defined timezone. It currently does not
>   support per-user timezones. All the tasks: system's and user's will be
>   run based on the configured timezone. Even if a user specifies the TZ
>   environment variable in his crontab this will affect only the commands
>   executed in the crontab, not the execution of the  crontab  tasks
>   themselves.

Fedora's man page states it like this:

> The  CRON_TZ  variable specifies the time zone specific for the cron
>   table.  The user should enter a time according to the specified time
>   zone into the table.  The time used for writing into a log file is
>   taken from the local  time zone, where the daemon is running.

Given you're on Ubuntu I don't expect this to work but it might. I checked on Ubuntu 12.10.

Try something like this:

```
#m  h           d   m   wday    command
CRON_TZ=IST
5   0,6,12,18   *   *   *       /path/to/script.bash
```

#### All crons in a different TZ

If however you're aiming to run all your crons in a different timezone you could take the more dramatic tactic of changing the `TZ` for the cron daemon itself. Something like this in the stop/start script:

```
# /etc/init.d/crond
...
...
# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

[ -e /etc/sysconfig/$prog ] && . /etc/sysconfig/$prog

export TZ=IST
start() {
    if [ $UID -ne 0 ] ; then
        echo "User has insufficient privilege."
        exit 4
    fi
    [ -x $exec ] || exit 5
    [ -f $config ] || exit 6
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    daemon $prog $CRONDARGS
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
}
...
...
```

This is code from my Fedora crond stop/start script but a similar change could be made to your Ubuntu stop/start script for crond.

Comment: @sim - in which file I should add this?

Comment: This is a crontab entry so something like `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: I did "crontab -e" and added CRON_TZ=IST...it didnt work :-(

Comment: @tesster - yeah given it's Ubuntu it was a stretch. I think you're only option is to set the TZ for the entire crond.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter, but try putting the string "IST" in quotes.

In `cron.conf` or `/etc/default/cron`:

```
export TZ='IST'
```

Also, instead of using the short name, try using the long name:

```
export TZ='Asia/Kolkata'
```

Or put this in your `~/.profile` if you are doing crontabs

```
export TZ='Asia/Kolkata'
```

After making changes to this daemon's config file you need to restart it:

```
service cron restart
```

Comment: `cron.conf` in Ubuntu looks like a systemd file, are you sure we can add `export` in it? I want to set ` CRONDARGS="-s -m off"` to avoid mail (and log) but cannot find how to do it in Ubuntu.

Comment: Even though `/etc/default/cron` says it is deprecated adding `CRONDARGS="-s -m off"` will work (for now) because it is sourced in `/etc/init.d/cron`. `/etc/init/cron.conf` is a systemd config file and `export` may or may not work there but I could not find if it does.

Comment: It's deprecated because this thread is over 3 years old. Things have changed

Comment: yes and still on Ubuntu 16.04 it seems to be the only option to set `CRONDARGS`

Comment: Which would be irrelevant to a user who asked a question 3 years ago. Don't necro threads unless there's a good reason to do so.